# Sorting associative array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an associative array which has string as well as numeric keys as follows

```
  0 => array:4 [▶]
  "first" => array:4 [▶]
  1 => array:4 [▶]
  2 => array:4 [▶]
  "second" => array:4 [▶]
  3 => array:4 [▶]
  4 => array:4 [▶]
```

I want to sort this array such that elements with string keys should appear first then elements with numeric keys should appear. For Example

```
  "first" => array:4 [▶]
  "second" => array:4 [▶]
  0 => array:4 [▶]
  1 => array:4 [▶]
  2 => array:4 [▶]
  3 => array:4 [▶]
  4 => array:4 [▶]
```

I'm using PHP 7.4.7.

I have tried different sorting mechanism but nothing worked. Is this even possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`uksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) to sort based on keys with a custom comparator function. In this code, the function sorts non-numeric keys before numeric keys, and also sorts the keys in each group (so `first` comes before `second`):

```
$array = array(array(0), 'first' => array('first'), array(1),array(2), 'second'=>array('second'), array(3), array(4));

uksort($array, function ($ka, $kb) {
    if (is_int($ka)) {
        if (!is_int($kb)) return 1;
        return $ka - $kb;
    }
    else {
        if (is_int($kb)) return -1;
        return strcmp($ka, $kb);
    }
});
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [first] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
        )    
    [second] => Array
        (
            [0] => second
        )    
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/7ZbWT)

Comment: Yes it is working but one of the other array has been sorted in descending order. I mean `uksort` is sorting the numeric keys first then non numeric keys. previously that array was sorted correctly by default. any comment.

Comment: That should not be possible with this code,  it will either work for all or none of the arrays. Unless perhaps some of the keys are numeric strings, not integers?

Comment: I have created two example first is working but not second.
[First Example](https://3v4l.org/OFHHd)
[Second Example](https://3v4l.org/Rl5pf)
The difference in both array is that the second array has more elements in nested array than first.

Comment: @FahadShaikh sorry about the lack of response... it's been night time. Thanks to your examples I did see the typo in my code (`$ka` where I should have had `$kb`). I've corrected that. I see you figured it out yourself in the meantime, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Thnx to @Nick for making me familiar with `uksort`

I have modified the `uksort` function to return required output.

I have modified the `else` part of `if-else` condition where I checked if both keys `$ka` & `$kb` are non numeric then `strcmp` function will evaluate the result.

If `$ka` is non numeric while `$kb` is numeric then it will always returns false.

```
<?php
$array = array(array(0), 'first' => array('first'), array(1),array(2), 'second'=>array('second'), array(3), array(4));

    uksort($array, function ($ka, $kb) {
        if (is_int($ka)) {
                if (!is_int($kb)) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return $ka - $kb;
            }
            else {
                if (!is_int($kb)) {
                    return strcmp($ka, $kb);
                }
                return -1;
            }
    });
    print_r($array);
```

Output:

Array
(
[first] => Array
(
[0] => first
)

```
[second] => Array
    (
        [0] => second
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
    )
```

)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ai3Zs)

Other two examples mentioned in my comment are also working

[First Example](https://3v4l.org/gh85M)

[Second Example](https://3v4l.org/gh85M)